# How to generate excel2010 with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am generating excel2017 with phpexcel. i am facing problem with COUNTIFS() function. Is there any way to generate excel2010 with phpexcel?

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such format as Excel2010, that's simply a version of MS Excel. If you want to create an Excel BIFF-format (`.xls`) file, then you use the `Excel5` Writer; if you want to create an OfficeOpenXML (`.xlsx`) file, then you use the `Excel2007` Writer